# Adding an orderer to already existing channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Can anyone please guide me how can I add a new orderer from a new organisation to an already existing hyperledger fabric network. I have created all the certificates using fabric CA.

Answer (score -1):

Orderer is an organization, So the process is almost same as [adding a new organization](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/channel_update_tutorial.html).

The process is:

1. Prepare crypto material for new orderer
2. Add TLS certificate to System Channel
3. Fetch the latest configuration block for new orderer
4. Bring up new orderer container
5. Add new orderer end point to System Channel
6. Add TLS certificate to Application Channel
7. Add new orderer end point to Application Channel

We can find details on given link:
https://medium.com/@kctheservant/add-an-orderer-to-a-running-raft-based-orderer-cluster-b6a432da138c

Comment: Orderer is not an organization, orderer is a node like a peer with extra capabilities and any organization can host this not just OrdererOrg probably you have just limited to initial tutorials from HLF